# i was trying to upload a zip file using php codigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have many doubts regarding this.

1. In autoload.php, in $autoload[libraries] what library should specify for 
   uploading the file.
2. When I took a reference, I saw using

   $this->load->library('upload', $config);

and there is no library named upload in my files.
 3. Below is my controller

```
function cpanel_download_or_upload()
{
    if(isset($_POST[TAG_UPLOAD]))
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'zip';

        if ( ! is_dir($config['upload_path']) ) die("THE UPLOAD DIRECTORY DOES NOT EXIST");
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
           die("ERROR");
        } else {

            return array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        }
    }
    $this->load->view('CPANEL/access_file_from_or_to_cpanel.php');
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What version of CI are you working on? Have you tried adding the upload library to the autoload or your controller? does it throw an error when you do? Why do you say there's no upload library in your files? did you check on `system/libraries/` for a file named `Upload.php`?

Comment: maybe you're looking inside `application/libraries` - this is where you put in third party or custom libraries.